# strong good suffix rule for the Boyer-Moore Algorithm

Tags: algorithm, string-search, boyer-moore

So one of the exercises in my class was to perform the Boyer-Moore Algorithm with the pattern `abc` and the string `aabcbcbabcabcabc` and `abababababababab`. I was also meant to note the number of comparisons.

Which I had done using the extended bad character rule, however I was told today that one needs to use the strong good suffix rule once a match is found in the string. However, I'm a bit confused on how the strong good suffix rule would be used here as the pattern length is only 3.

When there is a full match, as the pattern `abc` has no border, when it is encountered in the string would I simply just shift by 3 symbols?

Thank You!

Comment: That would be the best thing to do. Any other idea?